# Injecting a fake concrete class via FakeItEasy and AutoFixture

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture, fakeiteasy

I've got a class I want to test where a concrete class (`MyClient`) is being injected.

```
private readonly MyClient _client;

public Sync(MyClient client)
{
    _client = client;
}
```

For testing we're using xUnit, AutoFixture and FakeItEasy. This all works quite well when injecting interfaces to a class.

However, when using the following test setup

```
[Theory]
[AutoFakeData]
public async Task It_should_invoke_client(
    [Frozen]MyClient geoClient,
    [Frozen]ILogger logger,
    Sync sync)
{
    // Act
    await sync.Run(null, logger);

    //Assert
    A.CallTo(() => myClient.SyncAllAsync(A<CancellationToken>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
}
```

The faked `GeoClient` isn't injected to the `sync` parameter. The created `sync` is stating the injected `MyClient` isn't a Faked object.

> System.ArgumentException : Object 'Some.Namespace.MyClient' of type Some.Namespace.MyClient is not recognized as a fake object.

When debugging through the `sync`, I see this is correct. A 'normal' `MyClient` has been injected to the system under test.

From what I understand from the documentation, this *should just work*. I'm probably missing some obvious step, but fail to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoFakeItEasy only provides fakes if the requested specimen is of a type that is either abstract or an interface. See [FakeItEasyRelay](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/6764f47c1eff039c274b08869213a734e2e58eea/Src/AutoFakeItEasy/FakeItEasyRelay.cs#L92):

```cs
return type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract || type.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface;
```

It appears that you could override this by providing a custom `ISpecimenBuilder` relay, but I've not tried.

Comment: Thanks, creating my own `ISpecimenBuilder` works. I've added it via `fixture.Customizations.Add(new ConcreteTypeSpecimenBuilder())` and the `IsFakeableSpecification` has a line `return type.GetTypeInfo().IsClass;` instead of the original. I'll check if I can refactor this code a bit to make it a bit better.

Comment: The cleanest solution I've come up with is to create a derived class of `FakeItEasyRelay`, which uses the base constructor to 'inject' my own `IRequestSpecification`, which in turn does a `return type.GetTypeInfo().IsClass;` (+ the original checks). This is added via the `fixture.Customizations.Add(new RelayForConcreteTypes());`